# Reading unknown number of lines from console

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I have to read unknown number of lines from stdin in python3. Is there a way to do this without any modules? One more question: How to denote end of input for multiple lines in python3?

Comment: I saw a similar question but was regarding python2. I tried importing sys but it doesn't stop when I enter a blank line. I don't need modules

Comment: Check my answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
a_lst = []          # Start with empty list
while True:
    a_str = input('Enter item (empty str to exit): ')
    if not a_str:   # Exit on empty string.
        break
    a_lst.append(a_str)
print(a_lst)
```

Comment: Can you answer the second part of my question?

Comment: I want to ask that will your code work if there is a EOF at the end. I know it works when I enter an empty line at the end. But I don't know how will the code behave if there is EOF at the end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191195/discussion-between-devesh-kumar-singh-and-tojrah).

Answer (score 3):

**We can use try and except in the following way**

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input())
        # Perform your operations
    except EOFError:
        # You can denote the end of input here using a print statement
        break
```